# Formula for calc fee deployment on-chain Candy Machine v3

Tags: candy-machine-v3, fee

Could someone say, where I can get formula for calc fee of Candy Machine v3 deployment on-chain? Or where can I search for it?

I found users reference to https://feecalc.live/, but it seems, it doesn't work now, I get a page with an error "domain has expired".